# Is it possible to update ACF Wysiwyg field programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I have to update ACF Wysiwyg field from php. I want to insert rendered (rendered from another Wysiwyg field) content into the field.

`update_field()` not working for Wysiwyg field. Is there any other solution for this?

I can't change the field type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the HTML using `html_entity_decode`. So it would be;

`update_post_meta($postid, 'key', html_entity_decode('HTML HERE'));`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this by using  :

update_post_meta($postid, 'ACFfieldid', $value);

or 
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );